# How do I extract table data in pairs using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: loops, beautifulsoup, python

My data sample :

```
<table id = "history">
<tr class = "printCol">
<td class="name">Google</td><td class="date">07/11/2001</td><td class="state">
<span>CA</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class = "printCol">
<td class="name">Apple</td><td class="date">27/08/2001</td>
</tr>
<tr class = "printCol">
<td class="name">Microsoft</td><td class="date">01/11/1991</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Beautifulsoup code :

```
table = soup.find("table", id = "history")

rows = table.findAll('tr')
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    for td in cols:
        print td.find(text=True)
```

Desired Output for MySQL storage (list):

```
['Google|07/11/2001|CA', 'Apple|27/08/2001', 'Microsoft|01/11/1991']
```

Output I have (difficult to associate the right date to the right company) :

```
Google
07/11/2001


Apple
27/08/2001
Microsoft
01/11/1991
```

I wrote a function to extract elements from each *tr* but I thought there is a much more efficient way of doing it all in the original *for* loop. I want to store them in a list as data pairs. Thoughts?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

List comprehension will make it easier:

```
table = soup.find("table", id = "history")
rows = table.findAll('tr')
data = [[td.findChildren(text=True) for td in tr.findAll("td")] for tr in rows]
# data now contains:
[[u'Google', u'07/11/2001'],
 [u'Apple', u'27/08/2001'],
 [u'Microsoft', u'01/11/1991']]

# If the data may contain extraneous whitespace you can clean it up
# Additional processing could also be done - but once you hit much more
# complex than this later maintainers, yourself included, will thank you
# for using a series of for loops that call clearly named functions to perform
# the work.
data = [[u"".join(d).strip() for d in l] for l in data]

# If you want to store it joined as name | company
# then simply follow that up with:
data = [u"|".join(d) for d in data]
```

The list comprehension is basically a reverse `for` loop with aggregation:

```
[[td.findNext(text=True) for td in tr.findAll("td")] for tr in rows]
```

translates into<sup>*****</sup>:

```
final_list = []
intermediate_list = []

for tr in rows:
    for td in tr.findAll("td")
        intermediate_list.append(td.findNext(text=True))

    final_list.append(intermediate_list)
    intermediate_list = []

data = final_list
```

<sup>*****</sup> Roughly - we are leaving out the awesomeness involving generators *not* building intermediate lists, since I can't add generators right now without cluttering the example.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for. Though it looks a little complicated, I like one liners. Thank you.

Comment: @ThinkCode - glad I could help! Just added a bit of explanation of the one-liner for you :-)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Sean. Python sure is awesome!

Comment: for val in data: print val doesn't work right? How do I split them for database entry?! Edit : Used this instead!

Comment: @ThinkCode - If you are using the lists, you can just access them as `val[0]` and `val[1]` - alternately, you can unpack it by doing `for company_name, date_incorporated in data: print company_name, ":", date_incorporated`.

Comment: interestingly, val[0], val[1] didn't work. Nor does for company_name, date_incorporated in data: print company_name, ":", date_incorporated. This works though : data = [u"|".join(d) for d in data]

Comment: Hi Sean, I modified the input file to include a 3rd data point which doesn't always occur. It is wrapped in <span> tags and beautifulsoup is fetching it as 2 blank lines. Do I have to do something different to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: @ThinkCode - I'd ask a new question about that :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5023/discussion-between-thinkcode-and-sean-vieira)

Comment: @SeanVieira When I use your answer I get an "extra" level of nested list like `[[[u'Google'], [u'07/11/2001']],
 [[u'Apple'], [u'27/08/2001']],
 [[u'Microsoft'], [u'01/11/1991']]]`

Answer (score 2):

Here is small variation of Sean answer if you need exactly what you wrote in question,

```
table = soup.find("table", id = "history")

rows = table.findAll('tr')

data = ['|'.join([td.findNext(text=True) for td in tr.findAll("td")]) for tr in rows]
print data
```

Comment: I added a pipe thinking that I can split while storing the data. Sean's solution has the data pairs which saves the splitting cost I believe. Thank you.