# How to extract whole data of a website using python?

Tags: python, angular, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to read data of tables from the following website: https://cdn.ime.co.ir , using the following code:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://cdn.ime.co.ir'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
```

But when I check the content of `soup` the data of the tables that I need to read aren't in there!

This is one of the tables that I like to read it's data that will be shown by clicking on it's above bar.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you for getting the website data, start with a `GET` request instead of `POST`.

`response = request.GET(<url>)`

[Differences between GET and POST](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

After that, you should use beautifulsoup4 for analysing the data inside the response:

[BS4 Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Regards!

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the data do I need is inside the tables that I can get their information using soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

Comment: Hi @ensan3kamel, you can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139797/how-do-i-extract-table-data-in-pairs-using-beautifulsoup or https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/extracting-data-html-beautifulsoup